# Minimum Population Size for pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame with values I want to group into bins which maximizes variance between the bins.

```
number_of_bins = 5
pd.cut(df['val'], number_of_bins)
```

However, my data has some outliers in it so my population sizes of those groups are quite small apart from the two middle ones. Is there an easy way to impose a minimum bin size of say 10% so my group populations aren't too small?

Comment: I don't think you can specify it to that degree.you can provide the intervals though... Not very sure what you mean by maximize variance between bins

Answer (score 2):

You may find [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html#pandas.qcut) useful:

```py
# array with a big outlier
z = np.append(np.arange(10), 500)

# split into 5 quintiles
labels = pd.qcut(z, 5, labels=False)
print(labels)
# [0 0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4]
```

Note we have approx 1/5 of the dataset in each bin, and so the outlier is included.